# Regex to remove [] and everything in them

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am having some troubles getting some regex to work to remove some text, I need `[text]` removing from `[text][maybehere]anytext`.

So basically the first set of [] and whatever is in them. The rest of the text can contain anything including spaces and may have another set of [].

I have this: `/\[.*\]/` but it is removing all of the brakets and contents.

I am using PHP

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the 4th parameter (replace limit) in [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace):

```
$str = preg_replace('/\[[^\]]*\]/', '', $str, 1);
```

Comment: @webnoob: For an understandable regex introduction check out http://regular-expressions.info/ - and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world for some regex crafting tools.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest

```
preg_replace('#\[.*?\]#', '', $stringVar, 1);
```

It will remove the first matching [] including it's content completely.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
"/^\[[^\]]*\](.*)$/"
```

Comment: some details could have helped, + you have a double quote in there missing